# get subcollection on basis of querying parent collection cloud firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get the all docs in subcollection after querying parent collection
I want to access all docs in "follow" collection as you can see screenshot only for the logged in user

this is my code

```
const getFollowers = async () => {
      const q = query(collection(db, "users"), where("uid", "==", user.uid));
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q, "follow");
      const data = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        data.push({ id: doc.id, data: doc.data() });
        // console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        setFollowingUsers(data);
      });      
    };
```

here is my database screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to first query the user doc, in order to get it's `id`, and then query the `follow` sub-collection, as follows (untested):

```
const q = query(collection(db, "users"), where("uid", "==", user.uid));
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
if (querySnapshot.size > 0) {
  const userDocSnapshot = querySnapshot[0]; // Normally only one doc in the querySnapshot
  const qFollowers = query(collection(db, "users", userDocSnapshot.id, "follow"));
  const querySnapshotFollowers = await getDocs(qFollowers);
  const data = [];
  querySnapshotFollowers.forEach((doc) => {
     data.push({ id: doc.id, data: doc.data()
  });
  setFollowingUsers(data);    
}
```

Note that `getDocs(q, "follow");` cannot work, see the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_?hl=en&authuser=0#getdocs).

You may be interested by this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-define-the-collectionreference-of-a-subcollection-in-javascript-sdk-v9-c0ffb0459695) which details different possibilities for defining the `CollectionReference` corresponding to a subcollection when using the JavaScript SDK Version 9.

*Side Note: Why don't you use the user's uid as Document ID of the its user doc? This would make things much easier.*